# Angular's redirectTo not updating the path in the address bar

Tags: routes, angular8, address-bar

I'm successfully redirecting according to my angular routing config:

```
  {
    path: 'mypath',
    redirectTo: 'myotherpath',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'mypath',
    children: [
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: MyComponent,
        },
    ]
  }
```

When you hit 'mypath' without passing an id parameter you are redirected to 'myotherpath'. Great, that all works, but in the address bar it still displays the old address (e.g. http://localhost/mypath) even though it's loaded the 'myotherpath' page.

Is this expected behaviour? I now have a page whereby the address bar is out of sync with what's being displayed. How can I configure it so that the address bar is updated once redirected?

### EDIT

To confirm - 'myotherpath' already has it's own entry for routing config, it can be navigated to directly. This is more of a redirect in case the 'mypath' is invalid (in the sense that an id hasn't been provided).

Answer (score 0):

"path" is just the name in the address bar,

this is want you want

```js
{
    path: 'myotherpath',
    redirectTo: 'myotherpath',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I think there's a misunderstanding - 'myotherpath' already has another entry in this routing config. If mypath has not been provided with an id value, I need it to bounce the user to myotherpath instead.